# SqlAlchemy button logic, changing from True, to None, to False

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm hoping to get some help with this. I believe my logic is flawed.

I have an application where you can rate different articles based on relevancy after a search. The toggle buttons are Relevant and Not Relevant. This is to determine if a particular article is relevant to a search, not relevant to a search, or undetermined.

Basic functionality of buttons:

When **none** of the buttons are selected:

- User clicks Relevant -> Set `RelevantFlag.state` to **True**
- User clicks Not Relevant -> Set `RelevantFlag.state` to **False**

When **Relevant** button is selected:

- User clicks Relevant -> Set `RelevantFlag.state` to **None**
- User clicks Not Relevant -> Set `RelevantFlag.state` to **False**

When **Not Relevant** button is selected:

- User clicks Relevant -> Set `RelevantFlag.state` to **True**
- User clicks Not Relevant -> Set `RelevantFlag.state` to **None**

A new `RelevantFlag` record will be added each time a user clicks a button. Selecting the Relevant button then selecting it again will toggle the button off. For instance, pressing Relevant twice and printing out the records:

`<'RelevantFlag:True'> <'RelevantFlag:None'>`

When the user clicks Relevant 3 times, records should be:

`<'RelevantFlag:True'> <'RelevantFlag:None'> <'RelevantFlag:True'>`

Instead, I'm getting

`<'RelevantFlag:True'> <'RelevantFlag:None'> <'RelevantFlag:None'>`

Here is the model class I'm working with:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    def mark_relevant(self, research, article):
        # If nothing is selected OR
        # NotRelevant is selected, set True state
        if (not self.has_marked_relevant(research, article) or
            self.has_marked_not_relevant(research, article)):
            relevant = RelevantFlag(
                user_id=self.id,
                research_id=research.id,
                article_id=article.id,
                state=True
            )
            db.session.add(relevant)

        # If Relevant already selected, set back to None
        elif self.has_marked_relevant(research, article):
            relevant = RelevantFlag(
                user_id=self.id,
                research_id=research.id,
                article_id=article.id,
                state=None
            )
            db.session.add(relevant)

    def mark_not_relevant(self, research, article):
        # If nothing is selected OR
        # Relevant is selected, set False state
        if (not self.has_marked_not_relevant(research, article) or
            self.has_marked_relevant(research, article)):
            not_relevant = RelevantFlag(
                user_id=self.id,
                research_id=research.id,
                article_id=article.id,
                state=False
            )
            db.session.add(not_relevant)

        # If Not Relevant already selected, set back to None
        elif self.has_marked_not_relevant(research, article):
            not_relevant = RelevantFlag(
                user_id=self.id,
                research_id=research.id,
                article_id=article.id,
                state=None
            )
            db.session.add(not_relevant)

    def has_marked_relevant(self, research, article):
        return RelevantFlag.query.filter(
            RelevantFlag.user_id == self.id,
            RelevantFlag.research_id == research.id,
            RelevantFlag.article_id == article.id,
            RelevantFlag.state).count() > 0

    def has_marked_not_relevant(self, research, article):
        return RelevantFlag.query.filter(
            RelevantFlag.user_id == self.id,
            RelevantFlag.research_id == research.id,
            RelevantFlag.article_id == article.id,
            RelevantFlag.state == False).count() > 0
```

And the RelevantFlag model

```
class RelevantFlag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    article_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('article.id'))
    state = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Relevant: {0}:{1}>'.format(
            self.user_id,
            self.state
            )
```

I'm stuck on how to incorporating two-button toggles that create records with different states. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: The `has_marked_*` methods seem to relate to the entire history, rather than the current state of the button.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Ah, that is not intentional. My problem seems to be in the `has_marked_` methods

Comment: Any idea how to get the current state of the button?

Comment: Set a timestamp on the flag records and select the most recent?

Comment: It's easier and faster if you replace `.count() > 0` with `.exists()`. What if I asked you to count the grains of sand on the beach, only to be interested in whether there are *any*? I'd save you a lot of time to come up with an accurate number if I'd just told you to stop as soon as you'd found a single grain

Comment: Try replacing `RelevantFlag.state==False` with `RelevantFlag.state==sqlalchemy.false()`. They're two different objects - and I think that is screwing up your query

Comment: I tried a combination of all your solutions above and it worked. Instead of a timestamp I made a query to get the most recent record then checked if it was None or not, and I replaced `.count()` with `.exists()`.
Thank you